# Virtualization on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, virtualization

I've seen that there is native support for virtualization in Windows 7, that you can even use an ISO to boot into a virtual machine.  That sounds pretty cool, but I'm curious about the support for running multiple virtual machines concurrently, using something like VMWare Server or MS Virtual Server.  Anyone have any experience?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a new version of Windows Virtual Machine available for Windows 7. It is currently in Beta but the same platform used to run Windows XP Mode. The new Virtual PC requires hardware assisted virtualization to work. More on the new Virtual PC can be found [here](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/). Virtual Server is not supported on Windows 7, and VMWare Server also complains.

[VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/) also runs happily on top of Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

I was under the impression that Windows 7 only virtualizes Windows XP, for backwards compatibility. You load up FoxPro, and it has problems with Windows 7 so it virtualizes Windows XP to run that window.

Also, you have to have a specific processor feature. Not all processors will support Windows 7 Virtualization.

You're better off with VMWare Server or MS Virtual Server.